# Using generic USB device drivers for windows

Tags: windows, usb, driver

What types of USB device drivers can be used without paying for Microsoft certification?

I want to make hardware and software that connects via USB. [This article](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device) explains how HID device profiles can be used.

My question: **What other types of profiles exist that I could use? And how closely does my device have to resemble what the driver is meant for?**

Specifically: I want to achieve the highest possible bandwidth - I'm making a high speed data logger. Could I for example use some sort of webcam driver to get the high bandwidth stream data? (Or would the data have to then be in some sort of image format?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What types of USB device drivers can be used without paying for
>   Microsoft certification?

To make it clear, you technically don't need to pay Microsoft anything to have USB device drivers working on a machine (they do need to be digitally signed, either through a CA or self-signed certificates).

> My question: What other types of profiles exist that I could use? And
>   how closely does my device have to resemble what the driver is meant
>   for?

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820.aspx) lists the USB device classes that Windows comes with drivers for out of the box:

- Audio Class
- Bluetooth Class
- Communications Device Class
- Content Security Class
- Imaging Class
- Hub Device Class
- Human Interface Device (HID) Class
- Mass Storage Class
- Media Transfer Protocol Devices
- Printer Class
- Smart Card Class
- Video Class

You want to try to "match" your application to one of the above classes if you want to take advantage of the built-in drivers. However, both the Communications and HID device classes allow for full-duplex transfer of arbitrary data, so either one of those is suitable if you just want to send bytes back and forth.

> Specifically: I want to achieve the highest possible bandwidth - I'm
>   making a high speed data logger. Could I for example use some sort of
>   webcam driver to get the high bandwidth stream data? (Or would the
>   data have to then be in some sort of image format

How high-speed do you need it? If it is less than 64,000 bytes/second (which is actually already pretty fast for a vast array of data logging applications), then the HID class through full-speed USB works just fine. Otherwise, you may try using the Communications device class. (I have direct experience only with the HID device class, though).

Note that the speed of data transfer is not the only consideration you need to take into account. USB is a bus, so the total bus bandwidth is shared amongst all the devices connected to it. To help manage this, USB defines different types of transfers: interrupts, isochronous, and bulk.

The HID class uses interrupt transfers, while the Communications class generally uses bulk transfers. Interrupt transfers tend have a much shorter latency than bulk transfers, so this may be an important consideration.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! My goal is literally as fast as possible, so I imagine bulk transfer is what I'd want. I think as a minimum I'd want to achieve 1Mb/s

Comment: @Jodes: I wouldn't rule out interrupt transfers just yet, because bulk transfers have a lower priority than interrupt or isochronous transfers (i.e. bulk transfers use whatever bandwidth is left after allocation to interrupt and isochronous devices). If you have the option to use high-speed USB (instead of full-speed), you can send about 20 megabytes/second using the HID class (which uses interrupt transfers).